Snowpark DataFrame: Why so many synonyms for the same class methods?
I suspect it must be for some backward compatibility. And I simply try to find out what was the reason behind. The Snowpark DataFrame API was inspired from the Apache Spark DataFrame API.
But why so many similar DataFrame class methods, with the same signatures and functionality, appear with two different names?
Just a few examples (but there are so many):

create_or_replace_temp_view and createOrReplaceTempView
to_df and toDF
group_by and GroupBy

Also, is there a preferred notation today? A best practice to follow, related to these calls?

Snowpark/dataframe.py

 # Add aliases for user code migration
createOrReplaceTempView = create_or_replace_temp_view
createOrReplaceView = create_or_replace_view
crossJoin = cross_join
dropDuplicates = drop_duplicates
groupBy = group_by
minus = subtract = except_
toDF = to_df
toPandas = to_pandas
unionAll = union_all
unionAllByName = union_all_by_name
unionByName = union_by_name
withColumn = with_column
withColumnRenamed = with_column_renamed
toLocalIterator = to_local_iterator
randomSplit = random_split
order_by = sort
orderBy = order_by
printSchema = print_schema


And associated issue: Add pythonic snake_case APIs for camelCase APIs #196 


Every function and variables will be in snake_case.

...

While supporting a smooth code migration from pyspark to snowpark, using snake_case is recommended to user's new code. So all sample code will use snake_case APIs.



Also PEP 8: Function and Variable Names:

Function and Variable Names
Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.
Variable names follow the same convention as function names.
mixedCase is allowed only in contexts where that’s already the prevailing style (e.g. threading.py), to retain backwards compatibility.

